# Why does my mesh keep breaking

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode

[image]
[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]When I watch tutorials I follow them as well as I possibly can but my mesh always ends up breaking.

Example the faces overlap vertices instead of being multiple faces, faces overlap them selves and kind of flicker like there taking up the same spaces.

Some of my mesh also ends up with vertices where they should be like they auto connect to another location

Comment: If you could add a screenshot of the problems you are having that would be very helpful.

Comment: added an image of my main issue that makes blender more annoying then its worth

Comment: Weird, not sure why that would be happening unless you are just extruding in a weird way

Comment: i have to fix this issue several times on a model

Comment: please give teh blend file

Comment: the models that have had the issue happen have already been fixed the image i posted was recreated its not a bug as i made it. I followed this when it happened https://youtu.be/_uNz9oWuwSw?t=183

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what tutorial you're following, but I think I see what happened.  It looks like you selected the opposing faces, then extruded them along the Y axis by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> like so:

[image: Extruding multiple faces along the Y plane]

Which has the unintended effect of squishing the far face inside the cube, since both are moving in the same direction. Which causes the overlapping mesh you're struggling with.

What you're probably wanting to do is extrude the two faces away from each other.  For this you'd press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, then <kbd>S</kbd> to resize them, and <kbd>Y</kbd> to still restrict it to the Y axis:

[image: Resizing extruded faces along the Y axis]

Or alternatively you could extrude just one of the faces with <kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd>, repeating as needed:

[image]